# Info about Custom Crud Query

Tags: java, spring-mvc, crud, spring-jdbc, jpa

How to write A crud Query which can only fetch two colmun from my db?
suppose there are 4 columns in my db - (id,city,pincode,state) and i need only city,picode from crudRepository query

Comment: Hi and welcome, please read how to ask a question here (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: select city, pincode from table

Comment: Parminder, The folks at StackOverflow help lots of people (just an observation.  I'm not any representation of SO), but you should consider giving more context.  For example, maybe show the SQL that you have tried to do.  If you haven't done any, then maybe ask the question a different way, perhaps build a table, show the code from your Spring app, something else?  I don't know.  Nothing personal.  I hope this helps you asked a specific question so you can get the help you need.

Comment: select city,zipcode from table;  wants to achieve result in the java object but not by using native

Answer (score 2):

For example, it can be done like this:

```
SELECT city, pincode 
FROM tableName;
```

Comment: I want to achieve this SELECT city, pincode FROM tableName; To get the result in java objects by using CRUD REPOSITORY QUERY  not by native query

Comment: For java? 
Need to use java jdbc related programming。

Comment: can you explain me how?  @10290164

Comment: The code is too long, I am looking for a site with an instance.

Answer (score 1):

If it is about SQL, then will help you:

```
SELECT table_name.city, table_name.pincode FROM table_name;
```

It works if there is already a connection to DB.

Comment: You forgot `;` at the end of the statement. It will not work with a full stop